# Where did pand go?

Tags: networking, routing, bluetooth

Most [guides](http://bluez.sourceforge.net/contrib/HOWTO-PAN) on [setting up a Bluetooth access point](http://www.clearevo.com/ecodroidlink/#setup_raspberry_pi) use a program named "pand" to do so. [Seemingly, this program was dropped in bluez5.](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1346036#p1346036) How can PAN be set up without it?

Answer (score -1):

**Bluez5 requires Kernel 3.5+**

For Debian, the following package manifest is required:

- libusb-dev
- libdbus-1-dev
- libglib2.0-dev
- automake
- libudev-dev
- libical-dev
- libreadline-dev

**Run the hciconfig to list Bluez IFACES**

```
$> hciconfig
hci0:     Type: $TYPE  Bus: $BUS
          BD Address: $BD_HMAC_ADDR  ACL MTU: $MTU
SCO MTU: $SCO_MTU
       $STATE(DOWN/UP)
       $RX(BYTES RECEIVED)
       $TX(BYTES TRANSMITTED)
```

**Bring your Bluez IFACE up**

```
$>hciconfig hci0 up
$>hciconfig
```

**Enable Advertising**

```
$>hciconfig hci0 leadv 0
```

**Bluez IFACE should now be advertising.**

```
$>hcitool lescan
$BLUEZ_HW_MAC_ADDR $DEVICE_ID
```